# Line Break on small devices - IPhone / Android

Tags: android, html, css, iphone, line-breaks

my problem is the line break (automatically) on an iPhone.

Example Code:

```
<span>example text</span>
```

this `span` is boxed with multiple `div`s and some other stuff, that it have to break into two lines on an iPhone 4. But it doesn't automatically.

So i tried to use this combined and single

```
word-break: break-all;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

It works on an iPhone but on any other device it destroys the normal line-break.

the expected result should be

```
example
text
```

the happened result

```
example te
xt
```

What should i do to get my expected result on any mobile device?

Thanks for reading, I'm sorry for my bad English.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`word-break: break-all;` and `word-wrap: break-word;` does the exact opposite of what you want. These css properties will allow words to be broken in the middle of a word. The reason why it doesn't break is because you're using the `<span>` tag, which is supposed to only take up one line. Consider using a `<div>` or `<p>` tag instead.

Comment: What's the reason for you to use `<span>`?

Comment: @Detilium Its my specification, it must be a span.

Comment: You could see if adding `display: block` to the span fixes the issue? But a block-level span is in essence the same thing as a `<div>`. It's hard to say what exactly is the solution for your specific issue since I'm not exactly sure what it look like right now on the iPhone 4 without images and since I don't know what css is being applied to the parent divs.

Comment: @KevinNi As Example, 1 Div Padding of 100px. inside a span with the text from above. on an iphone 4 screen it must break because its to long for it. but it doesn't.